# throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, deadlock, channel

Given the following simple Go program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func total(ch chan int) {
    res := 0
    for iter := range ch {
        res += iter
    }
    ch <- res
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go total(ch)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
    fmt.Println("Total is ", <-ch)
}
```

I am wondering if someone can enlighten me as to why I get

```
throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

thank you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you never close the `ch` channel, the range loop will never finish.

You can't send back the result on the same channel. A solution is to use a different one.

Your program could be adapted like this :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func total(in chan int, out chan int) {
    res := 0
    for iter := range in {
        res += iter
    }
    out <- res // sends back the result
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    rch  := make(chan int)
    go total(ch, rch)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
    close (ch) // this will end the loop in the total function
    result := <- rch // waits for total to give the result
    fmt.Println("Total is ", result)
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but is still interesting to understanding goroutines: if you add `fmt.Println("Exiting total")` after `out <- res` you may never see it, as the program may exit sooner, without waiting for the goroutines to complete.

Comment: I started learning Go a few days ago and I can't understand howcome res := 0 is being run only once? Isn't the whole function supposed to be run 3 times? Only the loop is running 3 times in your example.

Comment: @OybekToirov The whole function runs only once, the iteration progresses each time there's something in int `in` channel

Comment: This works only if you know how many results are there _in the `rch` channel, what happens if you have unknown count of more work? Without using a wait group, how can you accomplish it?

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to specify in the func signature that each channel is read or write?

Answer (score -3):

This is also right.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go do(c)
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    // close(c)
    fmt.Println("Total is ", <-c)
}

func do(c chan int) {
    res := 0
    // for v := range c {
    //  res = res + v
    // }
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        res += <-c
    }
    c <- res
    fmt.Println("something")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what was wrong with the original program.