# Reading a file line-by-line with concurrency

Tags: go, file-io, goroutine

**What I Want To Do**

In `GetLine`, I am trying to parse a file line-by-line using `bufio.Scanner` and a naive attempt at concurrency.
Following fetching the text in each line, I am sending it via a channel of `string` to the caller(`main` function). Along with the value, I am also sending errors and completion flag(via `done` channel). Thus, this should be able to fetch a new line to process in a separate goroutine while the current line is processed.

**What I Have Actually Done**

```
var READCOMPLETE = errors.New("Completed Reading")

func main() {

    filename := flag.String("filename", "", "The file to parse")
    flag.Parse()

    if *filename == "" {
        log.Fatal("Provide a file to parse")
    }

    fmt.Println("Getting file")

    names := make(chan string)
    readerr := make(chan error)
    done := make(chan bool)

    go GetLine(*filename, names, readerr, done)

    for {
        select {
        case name := <-names:
            // Process each line
            fmt.Println(name)

        case err := <-readerr:
            log.Fatal(err)

        case <-done:
            // close(names)
            // close(readerr)
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Processing Complete")
}

func GetLine(filename string, names chan string, readerr chan error, done chan bool) {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        names <- scanner.Text()
        //fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        readerr <- err
    }

    done <- true
}
```

**What I Get on Running**

Runtime Error: `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

**What have I Tried to Fix?**

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12400826/4927751) answer about the error message, I tried closing the channels `names` and `readerr` in the last clause of the `select` statement as shown in the comments. However, the program still crashes with a log message. I am unable to fix it further and would appreciate any help.
Resources for learning are welcome.

P.S: I am relatively new to GoLang and still learning how to work with the CSP model of concurrency in Go. Infact, this is my first attempt at writing a synchronous concurrent program.

Comment: The output of the deadlock error should tell you exactly what line each goroutine is stuck on, which should help you to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for replying. As of now, I have figured out that the issue is related to the complete execution of the `GetLine` goroutine while the `select` statement still expects to receive a value. Thus, this error is raised. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break statement in a select breaks out of the select. The application must break out of the for loop when done. Use a label to break out of the for loop:

```
loop:
    for {
        select {
        case name := <-names:
            // Process each line
            fmt.Println(name)

        case err := <-readerr:
            log.Fatal(err)

        case <-done:
            // close(names)
            // close(readerr)
            break loop
        }
    }
```

The code can be simplified by eliminating the done channel.

```
func main() {

    filename := flag.String("filename", "", "The file to parse")
    flag.Parse()

    if *filename == "" {
        log.Fatal("Provide a file to parse")
    }

    fmt.Println("Getting file")

    names := make(chan string)
    readerr := make(chan error)

    go GetLine(*filename, names, readerr)

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case name := <-names:
            // Process each line
            fmt.Println(name)

        case err := <-readerr:
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            break loop
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Processing Complete")
}

func GetLine(filename string, names chan string, readerr chan error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        names <- scanner.Text()
    }
    readerr <- scanner.Err()
}
```

In this specific example, the code can be restructured to separate receiving names from receiving the error.

```
func main() {
    filename := flag.String("filename", "", "The file to parse")
    flag.Parse()

    if *filename == "" {
        log.Fatal("Provide a file to parse")
    }

    fmt.Println("Getting file")

    names := make(chan string)
    readerr := make(chan error)

    go GetLine(*filename, names, readerr)

    for name := range names {
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
    if err := <-readerr; err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Processing Complete")
}

func GetLine(filename string, names chan string, readerr chan error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        names <- scanner.Text()
    }
    close(names) // close causes range on channel to break out of loop
    readerr <- scanner.Err()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! TIL: `break` can be used to break out of a `select` statement in Go. Is there an alternative to using label here? Any idiomatic Go pattern?

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi You can avoid having to use labels if you put the `for` statement into a function (which may be a function literal), and use `return` instead of `break loop`.

Comment: The label is the idiomatic way to break out of a `for { select { } }`.  The code can be restructured to avoid the `for { select { } }` and therefore avoid the label. See updated answer.