# Go Tour #10: Lost in concurrency

Tags: go, web-crawler

I've been trying to do all the tour of go tutorials and I'm stuck at [the web crawler exercise](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10).

I thought I finished it, but the output is inconsistent and I don't have enough concurrency experience to figure out why.

[Here's](https://play.golang.org/p/2h8C8uGohh1) my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}
var cache = struct {
    fetched map[string]bool
    sync.Mutex
}{fetched: make(map[string]bool)}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, c chan []string, quit chan int) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    go safeVisit(url, c, quit, fetcher)
    for {
        select {
        case <- quit:
            return
        case u:= <-c:
            for _, v:= range u {
                go Crawl(v, depth -1, fetcher, c, quit)
            }
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    c := make(chan []string)
    quit := make(chan int)
    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, c, quit)
}

func safeVisit(url string, c chan []string, quit chan int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    cache.Lock()
    defer cache.Unlock()
    if _, ok := cache.fetched[url] ; ok {
        quit <- 0
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    cache.fetched[url] = true
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Visited : %s, %q \n", url, body)
    c <- urls

}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "http://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/cmd/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "http://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "http://golang.org/",
            "http://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Here's some sample output

```
Visited : http://golang.org/, "The Go Programming Language" 
not found: http://golang.org/cmd/
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/, "Packages" 
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/os/, "Package os" 
**Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/, "Package fmt"** 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Different than the first the last package is missing (deliberately  in asterisks above)

```
Visited : http://golang.org/, "The Go Programming Language" 
not found: http://golang.org/cmd/
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/, "Packages" 
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/os/, "Package os"
```

And finally, even a deadlock in some runs:

```
Visited : http://golang.org/, "The Go Programming Language" 
not found: http://golang.org/cmd/
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/, "Packages" 
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/os/, "Package os" 
Visited : http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/, "Package fmt" 
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [select]:
main.Crawl(0x4bfdf9, 0x12, 0x4, 0x524220, 0xc420088120, 0xc420092000, 0xc420092060)
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:26 +0x201
main.main()
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:39 +0xab

goroutine 23 [select]:
main.Crawl(0x4bfdf9, 0x12, 0x3, 0x524220, 0xc420088120, 0xc420092000, 0xc420092060)
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:26 +0x201
created by main.Crawl
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:31 +0x123

goroutine 24 [select]:
main.Crawl(0x4c09f9, 0x16, 0x3, 0x524220, 0xc420088120, 0xc420092000, 0xc420092060)
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:26 +0x201
created by main.Crawl
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:31 +0x123

goroutine 5 [select]:
main.Crawl(0x4bfdf9, 0x12, 0x3, 0x524220, 0xc420088120, 0xc420092000, 0xc420092060)
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:26 +0x201
created by main.Crawl
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:31 +0x123

goroutine 6 [select]:
main.Crawl(0x4c0a0f, 0x16, 0x3, 0x524220, 0xc420088120, 0xc420092000, 0xc420092060)
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:26 +0x201
created by main.Crawl
    /home/kostas/development/challenges/go/helloWorld.go:31 +0x123
```

I assume it has something to do with concurrency and recursion. I've seen other solutions in github that uses WaitGroups and such, but it's not used at the tour of go so far, so i'd rather not use it yet.

***UPDATE***

I figured out what is going on and working on the issue. Basically sometimes the select statement gets stuck in an endless loop because the channels quit and c don't always execute in the expected order. I added a default case that prints("nothing to do") and the program sometimes looped forever, sometimes executed by luck in a correct manner. My exit condition is not right

Comment: How frequent is the deadlock? 1 in 10? I'm trying to reproduce it.

Comment: It's quite inconsistent. Sometimes 1 in 3 sometimes 1 in 10 then two in a row

Comment: Most common cause of this specific issue is channels not being closed. For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398359/throw-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock - I'm trying to measure the frequency and maybe will propose a solution. Not a go expert, so no guarantees.

Comment: can you show the `link` for the tutorial which you follow ?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10 I have an update, will post soon

Answer (score 2):

I think the case is quite clear. Your channels are messing. Multiple goroutines are recieving from a same channel, and golang just randomly pick one.

As you send a zero through `quit`, you never know which goroutine quits: it is randomly picked by the go sheduler. It is possible that a newly generated Crawl recieved from `quit` before recieving from `c` (even if both channel are ready).

And due to that, the `depth` is a mess and it makes numbers of `safeVisit` being called unstable, resulting `quit` issuing different (randomly) signal. Sometimes it is just not enough to quit all goroutines generated, and it is a deadlock.

Edit:

First you should understand what your task is. The `Crawl` function takes in an url, a dep and a fetcher, and it:

1. Fetch the url
2. Print the fetched body
3. Make new `Crawl` queue generated from the fetched url with `dep-1`

Though the tour ask you to "fetch" url in parellel, it is clear that step 2 and step 3 must happen after step 1, meaning it is normal for a single Crawl to wait for the fetch. That means, no need for a new goroutine to call `Fetch`.

And on step 3 each new `Crawl` call has no need to wait the previous to finish, so these calls should be parellel.

With these analysis, one can come to these code:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
    return
}
```

There is one more problem: dealing with a visited url. You have done it well, instead of sending a `quit`, just make it `func(string) bool` and call it directly: `if Visited(Url) { return }` and it is done.

A side note: the tour is really not good at teaching concurency. You may want to look go blog articles, like golang concurency patterns or share memory by communicating.

Comment: That is correct, how would you go on about fixing this? I'm fairly new to the elements of concurrency and go so I'm struggling to change my way of thinking

Comment: I tried to write some thoughts on it and edited it into the answer. I hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tips, will have a look tomorrow and accept the answer once i figure it out and spend some time. happy new year