# All channels are deadlocked

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying to use a for loop that continuously sends strings to different channels read by different goroutines.  However, it gives me the error "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"  Why is this happening?  I searched for some answers, but I couldn't find an answer for this situation.

```
func main() {
    var chans []chan string

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        chans = append(chans, make(chan string))
    }

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go sendString(chans[i])
    }

    for str := range chans[0] {
        fmt.Print(str)
    }
}

func sendString(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "a"
    ch <- "b"
    ch <- "c"
    ch <- "d"
}
```

The errors are here.  It prints "abcd", then generates the error, and if I delete the loop for printing, the program does not generate the error.

```
abcdfatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

 goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    C:/Users/YuanZheng Hu/Desktop/Go Test/test/test.go:18 +0x28d

goroutine 19 [chan send]:
main.sendString(0xc04203c120)
    C:/Users/YuanZheng Hu/Desktop/Go Test/test/test.go:24 +0x42
created by main.main
    C:/Users/YuanZheng Hu/Desktop/Go Test/test/test.go:15 +0x175

goroutine 20 [chan send]:
main.sendString(0xc04203c180)
    C:/Users/YuanZheng Hu/Desktop/Go Test/test/test.go:24 +0x42
created by main.main
    C:/Users/YuanZheng Hu/Desktop/Go Test/test/test.go:15 +0x175
exit status 2
```

---

I did the version using WaitGroup, but it seems not correct, and gives me the same error " all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!" where did I do wrong in the code below ?

```
func main() {
var myWaitGroup sync.WaitGroup
ch := make(chan string)
myWaitGroup.Add(1)
go sendString(ch, &myWaitGroup)


myWaitGroup.Wait()
close(ch)

time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
func sendString(ch chan string, pg *sync.WaitGroup) {
ch <- "a"
ch <- "b"
ch <- "c"
ch <- "d"
defer pg.Done()

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [throw: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398359/throw-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock)

Comment: @TrippKinetics I guess for that question, he closed  the channel, and use another one to output the result, but what I want to say is, is there a way to print the elements in channel using only one channel, without using receive function in another goroutine

Comment: If you want to put all the strings down a single channel you can use a sync.WaitGroup to wait until all the go routines have completed then close the channel in the main go routine

Answer (score 7):

The second for loop will block until the channel is closed so you need to close it in the sending function.  Also, you only read from the first channel so some of the data is lost.  Doing this:

```
func main() {
    var chans []chan string

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        chans = append(chans, make(chan string))
    }

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go sendString(chans[i])
    }

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        for str := range chans[i] {
            fmt.Print(str)
        }
    }

}
func sendString(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "a"
    ch <- "b"
    ch <- "c"
    ch <- "d"
    close(ch)
}
```

Will produce:

```
abcdabcdabcd
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7SoDKChnTbz

If you wanted to do this with a single channel as per your comment then you could add a wait group to close the channel once all the go routines are complete:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            sendString(c)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    for str := range c {
        fmt.Print(str)
    }

}
func sendString(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "a"
    ch <- "b"
    ch <- "c"
    ch <- "d"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/E_awt8UBK9v

Comment: Thanks! I also did a version using WaitGroup, but it gave me the same error, the code is above, why will that generate error ? do I have to use anonymous functions when using WaitGroup ?

Comment: Give the channel a size otherwise it will block until something read from it:https://play.golang.org/p/IxqyF42wwcv. More info here https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3

Comment: Obviously this requires knowing how many things will be sent down the channel up front whereas closing the channel in another routine does not

Comment: Thank you so much ,  I have one more question, in the first example you  gave, it does not sepcify the size of channel, but why the channel can take four strings without any receiving function ?

Comment: The range in the second for loop receives. That didn't work in your initial code because the deadlock was occurring at the end of the second for loop when the channel never closed. In the initial wait group code it locked in the send.