# Golang asynchronous and CPU usage

Tags: go, concurrency, cpu

I am learning Go concurrency, and my expectation is that using goroutines and channels should increase the concurrency. The program takes a few milliseconds to complete. But as the load increases the execution time keeps increasing though there is good amount of CPU idle.

I am sending 1200 QPS/TPS  to the program below to analyze the request to response times, and I see that overall execution time of the program increases over time. Also, the CPU usage is around 3-6%.

As I increase the QPS to 100,000, the execution time of the program increases to seconds (from milliseconds initially). But the CPU usage remains at 8-9%.

So why doesn't the program use the other 90-94% of the available CPU and complete execution of the program more quickly?

`ulimit -n` is 2000000.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func total(in chan int, out chan int) {
    res := 0
    for iter := range in {
        res += iter
    }
    out <- res // sends back the result
}

func check() {

    ch := make(chan int)
    rch := make(chan int)
    go total(ch, rch)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
    close(ch)       // this will end the loop in the total function
    result := <-rch // waits for total to give the result
    fmt.Println("Total is ", result)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        m := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {

            maingetpath := ctx.Path()
            urlPart := strings.Split(string(maingetpath), "/")
            func := urlPart[1]
            switch string(func) {
            case "white":
                check()
            default:
                ctx.Error("not found", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
            }
        }

        fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8080", m)
        defer wg.Done()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile; m in main is undefined. Also, a defer statement at the end of a function is redundant. Place it at or near the top or remove the defer. In this case you don't need the anonymous goroutine in main at all.

Comment: Ignore the part about m being undefined. I got confused by your wonky indentation. So the question is why the goroutine in main doesn't make your program faster? Because adding it makes no difference at all, that's why. You're just replacing the main goroutine with the anonymous one. main does absolutely nothing but wait.

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: so what about the CPU usage...Even if i remove anonymous go in main.. i am still at 3-6% CPU, and as the QPS increases the execution time of the program increases. Why cant the CPU increase to 90% and give me better execution time for increase QPS

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do in this little server.

1) You are creating a WaitGroup and adding 1 to it, calling a anonymous go routine, and waiting in main, this does nothing more then move your main to the anonymous function.

2) Lets look at what your are doing in the `check` and `total` functions:

```
func total(in chan int, out chan int) {
    res := 0
    // this will just pull the value, and then wait till the next value 
    // is pushed... till you close the "in" channel
    for iter := range in {
        res += iter
    }
    out <- res // sends back the result
}

func check() {

    ch := make(chan int)
    rch := make(chan int)
    go total(ch, rch)
    // we are pushing this value into a unbuffered channel...
    ch <- 1  // this gets pushed and waits until it is pulled in the total function 
    ch <- 2  // this gets pushed and waits until it is pulled in the total function 
    ch <- 3  // this gets pushed and waits until it is pulled in the total function 
    close(ch)       // this will end the loop in the total function
    result := <-rch // waits for total to give the result
    fmt.Println("Total is ", result)
}
```

Please help me understand how this would use any concurrency when it is completely synchronous?

Maybe if you put the call to `check` in a go routine it would be a little more efficient, but still really makes no sense to me.

Comment: It is asynchronous, i was following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398359/throw-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock

Comment: stating it again, doesn't make it more correct. @Popmedic is right. Although there is a go routine doing some work, the caller of the routine just blocks.